# remove index.php from url only for the client

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I know there are some questions like this out there but the solutions are not helpful for me.
I´m using htaccess to redirect to the index.php if the request file isn´t defined (code above).
I´d like to add a code-line that if the user requests for example:
http://www.example.com/test/index.php
he will redirect to
http://www.example.com/test/
but internal it will redirect to the index.php.
Is there a way to extend my code so that it works like I want it to?

```
   # Add Slash
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/$|\.) 
    RewriteRule (.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]

# Redirect to index.php if the following sites were not match
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(php|sql|tgz|gz|txt|ttf|TTF|log|txt|ini|html|xml|xhtml|htm)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/phpinfo.php$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/out.php$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sitemap[^0-9]*\.xml$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/robots.txt$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?dir=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?dir=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Complete code:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html

Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Take off index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*/)index\.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(php|sql|tgz|gz|txt|ttf|TTF|log|txt|ini|html|xml|xhtml|htm)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/((index|phpinfo|out)\.php|robots\.txt|sitemap[^0-9]*\.xml)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?dir=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php?dir=$1 [QSA,L]

# Add Slash for non-files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thank you. I think if you put the code in the htaccess alone without my code above it will work.
It will have problems with my redirect to the index.php:
If you put your code above my code an than test it you will see what I mean. (further in the next comment)

Comment: The problem is, that until now all redirects to the index.php will be performed with a hidden paramter ?dir=[URI]. The client will not see this parameter but the index.php can work with it. So after I´ve pasted your code above my this hidden parameter will be visible. I don´t know why but now if I want to access a not existing directory (redirected with mod_rewrite to index.php) for example test/ it will redirect to index.php?dir=test/ but that shouldn´t appear. The parameter ?dir should not appear for the client

Comment: Thank you for the reply.
Ok, the first problem is solved, but a second appears.
create a directory for example css and put a css-file inside. After that try to open the css-file in your browser: domain.com/css/file.css -> You will get a NOT FOUND error.
If you want, I have made a live demo with the code you´ve posted. You can tell me and I´ll send you the login data for the server.

Comment: Yes I got it, I have a call now and will investigate it an hour.

Comment: I logged into to your server but it showed everything in German and I couldn't guess where a filemanager would be. I wanted to understand your directory strcucture and try some tweaking into .htaccess

Comment: I made a small change and it seems it is working now. `http://web19.dehamd004.servertools24.de/css/css.css` is also not throwing any 404 now.

Comment: Thank you again for taking the time. I´m sorry but it does not seem to be ready:
if you try to open http://web19.dehamd004.servertools24.de/hello/world/ you will be redirected to http://web19.dehamd004.servertools24.de/?dir=/hello/world/
that should not happen.. :( It should only redirect internal with the parameter ?dir= but the client url should be without this get parameter.

Comment: Alright I have made some further changes to your .htaccess, pls try now.

Comment: Hey Anubhava,
thank you a lot for helping me! I could not solve the problem without you. Could you help me to fix the last issue?
it is possible to call the index.php of a sub-directory, e.g. /test/one/index.php. It´s because it is an existing file. But that should also redirect to the index.php in the root directory.
Is it possible to fix this last thing? that would be really fantastic. can not thank you enough, I've played around for so long

Comment: Are you saying that `/test/one/index.php` should load `/index.php` internally?

Comment: If you request /test/one/index.php it should
1.) ... replace the index.php for the client (not internally)
2.) ... redirect to the index.php in the root (/index.php)
3.) ... set the ?dir= param to ?dir=/test/one/index.php internally
But only for index.php files which are not from the root directory. All other existing files should be directly accessible (no redirect)

Comment: I am sorry I tried to accommodate and be flexible as much as possible with the requirements that went well beyond the originally posted problem. But this is all sounding too fancy for me. Even if I am able to manage these new set of requirements i'm almost certain it will break something else.

Comment: that's too bad but I can understand it. However, it must be changed only one thing: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f checks if the file does not exist and if true, it will redirect to the index.php in the root directory. So this statement must be extended: If the file does not exist or  the file is an index.php not in the root directory.
So, if you request /test/one/index.php it will be:
(false or true) = true = redirect to index.php